# How to setup a DBIx::Class schema with Moose -- the definite guide

Tags: perl, moose, dbix-class

I found it rather difficult to find information about how to assemble a `DBIx::Class` schema structure using `Moose`. How to do that correctly (essentially working) and in modern Perl (good style, fast, without warnings)?

These are my goals:

- follow Moose' [`Moose::Manual::BestPractices`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/BestPractices.pod), especially:

  - use `namespace::autoclean` and
  - use `__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable`.
- use common base classes for `Result` and `ResultSet`
- when using any magic tricks have a comment explaining them (during research I found a guide suggesting `sub BUILDARGS { $_[2] }` explained by [*don't ask*](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=969609))
- move common code, e.g. `MooseX::NonMoose` (if necessary) or `__PACKAGE__->load_components`, into common base class as suggested by [`DBIx::Class::Manual::Cookbook`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Manual::Cookbook#Move-Common-Startup-into-a-Base-Class)

These are the problems I ran into:

- when using `__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable` I got warnings like `Not inlining 'new' for MyApp::Schema::Result::MyTable since it is not inheriting the default Moose::Object::new`
- when moving all calls to `__PACKAGE__->load_components` to the `Result` base class my `datetime` columns didn't get inflated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solutions to the problems that arose:

- `make_immutable` conflicts with a non-`Moose` `new` constructor: this is automatically handled by `use MooseX::NonMoose`; in contrast to its documentation no further arguments or options are necessary; beware that `DBIx::Class::Schema` has no `new` method and therefore, `MyApp::Schema` does **not** need this helper
- `InflateColumn::DateTime` not inflating when loaded in base class: This was triggered by the order of components given to `load_components()`; there is no hint in the documentation that order should matter and I've filed [a bug report](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=93976) about this; reordering helped

With the solutions above included my example DBIx::Class schema with Moose looks like this:

**Schema class:**

```
package MyApp::Schema;

use Moose; # we want Moose
use MooseX::MarkAsMethods autoclean => 1; # this helps removing unused symbols like Moose keywords
# do NOT 'use MooseX::NonMoose' here because Schema class has no 'new' method

extends 'DBIx::Class::Schema'; # the Moose way of inheritance

# load all table modules automatically
__PACKAGE__->load_namespaces(
    # ResultSet class for tables without custom ResultSet class
    # (would be DBIx::Class::ResultSet otherwise)
    default_resultset_class => '+MyApp::Schema::ResultSet',
);

# tell Moose this class is finished: some Moose stuff is removed and things go faster
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

1;
```

**Common `Result` base class:**

```
# a base class for all table class of this app
package MyApp::Schema::Result;

use Moose;
use MooseX::MarkAsMethods autoclean => 1;
use MooseX::NonMoose; # this is important for correctly handling DBIx::Class' new

extends 'DBIx::Class::Core';

# this is the right place to implement generic stuff

# DBIx::Class::Cookbook recommends loading components in a central place
__PACKAGE__->load_components(qw/
    InflateColumn::DateTime
    ...
/);

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

1;
```

**Common `ResultSet` base class:**

```
package MyApp::Schema::ResultSet;

use Moose;
use MooseX::MarkAsMethods autoclean => 1;
use MooseX::NonMoose;

extends 'DBIx::Class::ResultSet';

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

1;
```

**Example `ResultSet` class for table `my_table`:**

```
package MyApp::Schema::ResultSet::MyTable;

use Moose;
use MooseX::MarkAsMethods autoclean => 1;

extends 'MyApp::Schema::ResultSet';

sub oldest {
    my $self = shift;

    $self->search({}, {order_by => {-ASC => 'date'}})->first;
}

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

1;
```

**Example `Result` class for table `my_table`:**

```
package MyApp::Schema::Result::MyTable;

use Moose;
use MooseX::MarkAsMethods autoclean => 1;

extends 'MyApp::Schema::Result';

__PACKAGE__->table("my_table");

__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
    id   => {data_type => "integer", is_auto_increment => 1},
    date => {data_type => "date"},
);

__PACKAGE__->set_primary_key("id");

__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;

1;
```

Comment: use strict; and use warnings; is enabled automatically by use Moose and not required. I use namespace::autoclean instead of MooseX::MarkAsMethods which works fine for me too.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I read a ton of documentation today and can't find the exact place recommending `MooseX::MarkAsMethods` over `namespace::autoclean` right now. Do you think there's a good reason to stick to any of both?

Comment: Thanks for the guide, I'm favoriting this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734892/why-doesnt-use-overload-work-with-use-namespaceautoclean addresses namespace::autoclean and MooseX::MarkAsMethods.

Comment: @Oesor Thank you for that link. According to one of the answers there `MooseX::MarkAsMethods` was invented to address some problems of `namespace::autoclean` with advanced (not to say weird) uses of `Moose`. So it seems to be the safest way to keep it like that.

Answer (score 5):

What's wrong with using `use_moose` in [DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/ILMARI/DBIx-Class-Schema-Loader-0.07039/lib/DBIx/Class/Schema/Loader/Base.pm#use_moose)? (e.g. `dbicdump -o use_moose=1 MyApp::Schema <dsn> <user> <pass>`

This is what `use_moose=1` in `DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader` 0.07039 generates for the schema:

```
use utf8;
package MyApp::Schema;

# Created by DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader
# DO NOT MODIFY THE FIRST PART OF THIS FILE

use Moose;
use MooseX::MarkAsMethods autoclean => 1;
extends 'DBIx::Class::Schema';

__PACKAGE__->load_namespaces;


# Created by DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader v0.07039 @ 2014-03-19 22:50:18
# DO NOT MODIFY THIS OR ANYTHING ABOVE! md5sum:7Hx1RMeFsxCqo5YaLOzPdQ


# You can replace this text with custom code or comments, and it will be preserved on regeneration
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable(inline_constructor => 0);
1;
```

And the Result Class:

```
use utf8;
package MyApp::Schema::Result::Example;

# Created by DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader
# DO NOT MODIFY THE FIRST PART OF THIS FILE

use strict;
use warnings;

use Moose;
use MooseX::NonMoose;
use MooseX::MarkAsMethods autoclean => 1;
extends 'DBIx::Class::Core';

...yadda...


# Created by DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader v0.07039 @ 2014-03-19 22:50:18
# DO NOT MODIFY THIS OR ANYTHING ABOVE! md5sum:yTmu6Rh9TAEwxqgDClBdtg


# You can replace this text with custom code or comments, and it will be preserved on regeneration
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
1;
```

And here's the documentation for [creating a Moosified ResultSet class](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aResultSet#CUSTOM-ResultSet-CLASSES-THAT-USE-Moose)

Looks like it does have some extraneous `use strict` and `use warnings` but no biggie.
The good part is that if anything changes, hopefully the `DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader` will be updated to account for any needed changes.

Apologies if I'm missing the point.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I've started to develop database tables by writing the `Result` classes and deploy the database using the schema. I could have checked what the loader generates for my deployed schema but I still find it useful to have a template for writing a nice schema in the first place. Also I found some differences between different manuals and start the community wiki article to begin with a definite answer.

Comment: This should be chosen to be the right answer. It is the officially documented and supported method of dbicdump (part of DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader) to create Moose compatible DBIx::Class files ... See https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader::Base#use_moose